# Boost build fatal error LNK1105

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, boost, build, installation

Ok,
I'm having some problems with building boost (I need the build version)

**What is the problem**

Every time I try to run bootstrap.bat I get this error after a few seconds:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1105: Cannot close file "bin.ntx86\b2.exe".

"cl"  "/Fdbin.ntx86/" "/Fobin.ntx86/" /Febin.ntx86\b2.exe "-DNDEBUG" "- ...

...failed [COMPILE] bin.ntx86\b2.exe...
...skipped bjam.exe for lack of b2.exe...
...failed updating 1 target...
...skipped 1 target...
```

**System specifications**

- Windows 7
- Visual Studio 10 Express
- 64bit

**What I already tried**

- Deactivate Comodo Internet Security Premium
- Run vcvars32.bat
- b2.exe is NOT running (did reboot in order to ensure)

Comment: did you start your command prompt with administrative privileges? also there is a maximum character length of 256 with NTFS, if your filenames + directory names are too long it can cause failures

Comment: I did run it as admin + the filename and path are way shorter than 256 chars

Comment: @Layne I don't know if you're still having this problem, but I've just had a similar problem building LibMySQL (LNK1105 errors), and deactivating Comodo Internet Security Premium was not sufficient. I had to completely uninstall it, and my problem went away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've experienced the same error. In my case that was the behavior blocker of Comodo Antivirus causing trouble.

Comment: Exactly. I would have never thought of that. Vote up!

Comment: Removing Comodo Antivirus has fixed this error for me, as well as a host of other problems I was having with other programming tools. Note: turning it off was **not** sufficient for me, I had to uninstall it completely.

Comment: Accepted in combination with the comment about uninstalling it.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced the same problem recently (Windows 8.1, Boost 1.57). Even after exiting Comodo Internet Security, COMODO Internet Security Helper Service (cmdagent.exe) remains active. Failing to stop it from the Services snap-in, I've changed the start type of the service from Automatic to Manual and killed the process with Process Explorer from Sysinternals Suite. After that, Boost bootstrap worked.